# Program crashing when adding object to NSArray

Tags: ios, exception, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, ios5

I have the following `IBAction` set up:

```
#define FAVORITES_KEY @"GraphViewController.Favorites"
- (IBAction)addToFavorites:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *favorites = [defaults objectForKey:FAVORITES_KEY];
    if (!favorites) favorites = [NSMutableArray array];
    [favorites addObject:self.program];
    [defaults setObject:favorites forKey:FAVORITES_KEY];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

The first time this action is called it all works well, the object is added to my array and saved to `NSUserDefaults` without a problem, after that first call it will throw an exception when adding to the `favorites` array, if I try to step over the break it will say this:

```
Single stepping until exit from function objc_exception_throw, 
which has no line number information.

Catchpoint 3 (exception thrown).
```

Anyone had a similar issue or might know what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` returns an immutable array, so you need to convert it:

```
NSMutableArray *favorites = [[defaults objectForKey:FAVORITES_KEY] mutableCopy];
if (!favorites) favorites = [NSMutableArray new];
...
[favorites release];
```

Comment: That did it, small details like that are good to know. Gotta remember iOS always works with unmutable copies